# MEF vs Unity import into view model

Tags: unity-container, mef

When using unity you can import the container in the constructor of a view moder per say.

But how would I do import a MEF container into a view model to resolve instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it is not a great idea to be passing round the container, as you end up using it as more of a *service-location* mechanism, but should you wish to do so, you would need to manually export the container, e.g.:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeExportedValue(container);
```

This will enable you to import it:

```
[Import]
public CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }
```

Or:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyClass(CompositionContainer container) { }
```

Comment: I agree about the service location anti-pattern. I have done a lot of looking around without finding a good answer to my problem though - if I have a lot of things I need to import into view models, and I am reluctant to use [Import] (preferring constructor injection), how can I go about this without having huge constructors (this problem is amplified with inheritance, where subclasses must also provide the huge constructor). Any good ideas?